# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje de error en formulario? - Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema, quiero mostrar un mensaje de error en el *HTML* mostrando que ya existe ese id del empleado pero no logro hacerlo, mi idea era hacer un `if` y dependiendo el error mostrar el mensaje pero no logro hacerlo, estoy trabajando el backend con *Laravel* y *MySQL*.

**TS**

```
onSubmit() {
  this.Jarwis.addpersonal(this.personal).subscribe(data => {
    this.messageService.add({ key: 'success', severity: 'success', detail: 'Personal agregado' });
    setTimeout(() => { window.history.back(); }, 1000);
  }, error => this.onlyerrors(error)      
  );
}

onlyerrors(error: any) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

**Mensaje:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: ya elimine la imagen y lo puse en codigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de lograr lo que buscas.

Por ejemplo, si quisieras mostrar un mensaje de error sobre el formulario.

Podrías tener el siguiente HTML.

```
<div [hidden]="!requestFailed">
   <small>{{ error }}</small>
</div>
```

Luego, en el controlador, debes tener dos variables públicas, `requestFailed` y `error`.

Y al momento de capturar el error podrías hacer lo siguiente.

```
error: string;
requestFailed: boolean;
...

this.Jarwis.addpersonal(this.personal).subscribe(data => {
    // Código
}, res => {
    this.requestFailed = true;
    this.showError(res);
});

...
showError(res: any) {
    // Si el error es que ya existe ese id de empleado, mostrar el mensaje apropiado
    // Una forma es manejar códigos de error
    
    this.error = 'El id de empleado está repetido';
}
```

Comment: lo trate de hacer y me dice que res.error.code es undefined

Comment: Eso era un ejemplo porque depende de como este estructurado tu backend. Sin embargo, con lo que muestras no veo una forma fácil de distinguir los tipos de errores que se pueden presentar. Otra opción sería comparar el mensaje que devuelves, pero no me parece lo más ideal.

Comment: ya lo pude resolver, segui tu consejo con como estaba estructurado mi backend entonces busque y no puse las reglas en el request puse
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id_empleado' => 'required|unique:personales'
           
        ];
    }